# Typescript : Can't find module at execution

Tags: module, typescript, require, ecmascript-5, commonjs

I've been struggling with the different ways to make modules in Typescript, trying to encapsulate my code elegantly. However, I think I'm lost with how some things are supposed to work.

Essentially, I'm trying to make two projects work together :

- A type definitions for the operations of an API (https://github.com/Protectator/riotgamesapi-typedef)
- A library in Node.js using these definitions to make calls (https://github.com/Protectator/riotgamesapi-typenode)

The type definitions seem to be ok. The problems come with the library. So I'm trying to keep the definitions in a module named `riotGamesApi`, and an other module named `riotGamesTypeNode` for the library. I tried importing the first in the second, and the pre-compiler doesn't detect anything wrong.

I also started writing tests using mocha for my library. Again, the pre-compiler doesn't find anything wrong in my code.

Here is what I'm currently doing with the modules :

File **[riotgamesapi.d.ts](https://github.com/Protectator/riotgamesapi-typedef/blob/master/riotgamesapi.d.ts)** (type definitions)

```
declare module riotGamesApi {
    export module champion {
        [...]
    }
    [some more exports]
}

declare module "riotGamesApi" {
    export = riotGamesApi;
}
```

File **[riotgamesapi-typenode.ts](https://github.com/Protectator/riotgamesapi-typenode/blob/import-issue/src/riotgamesapi-typenode.ts)** (library)

```
///<reference path="../lib/riotgamesapi-typedef/riotgamesapi" />
///<reference path="../typings/node/node" />

import * as api from "riotGamesApi";

export module riotGamesTypeNode {
    [some classes here]
}

export = riotGamesTypeNode;
```

File **[riotgamesapi-typenode-tests.ts](https://github.com/Protectator/riotgamesapi-typenode/blob/import-issue/test/riotgamesapi-typenode-tests.ts)** (library tests)

```
///<reference path="../lib/riotgamesapi-typedef/riotgamesapi" />
///<reference path="../src/riotgamesapi-typenode" />

import * as api from 'riotGamesApi';
import * as rtnode from '../src/riotgamesapi-typenode';

[Using rtnode in code]
```

But after compiling everything (with gulp using `commonjs` and `es5`), when I try to run the tests, this error is encountered :

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '../src/riotgamesapi-typenode'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    [...more error lines...]
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, as this seems to be the only way the pre-compiler doesn't warn me about something. I'm surely missing some things, but then so is the pre-compiler ?

I've linked to the contents of the complete files so you can look for more info if you need, or try it yourself by cloning the git. (I'm using gulp for this, the task to test the code is `gulp test`)

Thank you in advance for any piece of advice or solution you might have, because I've been stuck with this for some time now... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your build output directory, there's no `src` dir in there so `../src/riotgamesapi-typenode` in your tests will never be resolved to `riotgamesapi-typenode.js`. Fix your Gulp config to output the expected directory structure.

I should also mention that mixing namespaces (AKA internal modules) with external modules as you do in `riotgamesapi-typenode.ts` is generally a bad idea, and using reference path comments is no longer a recommended practice (reference them in your Gulp task instead).

Comment: Thank for you answer. I've been trying to reference modules without using paths, but I just can't manage to make it work. In the file "riotgamesapi-typenode.ts", I'm now using only `module riotGamesTypeNode` instead of the "export" statement. Is this the correct way to do it ? Because the test file, even after referencing it using `///<reference path="../src/riotgamesapi-typenode" />`, the statement `import * as rtnode from 'riotGamesTypeNode';` still can't find the module (tells me this at compile time). Can you see what I'm doing wrong here then ? (I've pushed a new version to git too)

Comment: @Protectator You're trying to use an ES6-style import statement to import an internal module, it doesn't work like that, it only works with external modules. I've fixed things up for you and submitted a [PR](https://github.com/Protectator/riotgamesapi-typenode/pull/2), this isn't necessarily the cleanest way to set things up but at least it works now and you can improve on it if need be.

Comment: Yeah, the changes you made are working. Thank you so much for that help, I'm looking at how you've done this :) I can finally work on what I initially planned.